# Wildcard escaping JPA Specifications

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA Specifications Executor to implement search via records based on the user's input on UI.
For instance, one of the inputs should be searched in column `message` using LIKE clause. Currently I have done it like this:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchOptions.getSearchString())) {
     String likeExpression = String.format("%%%s%%", searchOptions.getSearchString());
     specifications = specifications.and(
         (root, query, cb) -> cb.like(root.get("message"), likeExpression));
}
```

The problem is, if the user's input contains wildcards like `%` or some text inside `[]`, I does not search for it as a literal, but treat is as a wildcard.

Can anyone suggest me how to avoid this and always search for the literal text in the column without having to manually escape every such character in java code?

RDBS I am using is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You should be binding a parameter instead of inserting it into your expression string.

```
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = build.createQuery( Person.class );
Root<Person> personRoot = criteria.from( Person.class );
 criteria.select( personRoot );
 ParameterExpression<String> eyeColorParam = builder.parameter( String.class );
 criteria.where( builder.equal( personRoot.get( Person_.eyeColor ), eyeColorParam ) );
 TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery( criteria );
query.setParameter( eyeColorParam, "brown" );
List<Person> people = query.getResultList();
```