# Spring Data JPA Specifications and SQL Injection

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, sql-injection

I am working on getting back up to speed on Spring, Spring Data and JPA.  I was interested in implementing the `Specification`s piece to enable a more dynamic query.

Say I have the following methods:

```
protected String containsLowerCase(String searchField) {
    return WILDCARD + searchField.toLowerCase() + WILDCARD;
}

protected Specification<T> attributeContains(String attribute, String value) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        return value == null ? null : cb.like(
                cb.lower(root.get(attribute)),
                containsLowerCase(value)
        );
    };
}

@Override
public Specification<Widget> getFilter(WidgetListRequest request) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> Specifications.where(
            Specifications.where(nameContains(request.getSearch()))
            .or(descriptionContains(request.getSearch()))
    )
            .and(testValBetween(request.getMinTestVal(), request.getMaxTestVal()))
            .toPredicate(root, query, cb);
}

private Specification<Widget> nameContains(String name) {
    return attributeContains("name", name);
}
```

And in my service I call like:

```
    WidgetListRequest request = new WidgetListRequest();
    request.setSearch(search);
    request.setMinTestVal(minTestVal.doubleValue());
    request.setMaxTestVal(maxTestVal.doubleValue());
    return widgetRepo.findAll(widgetSpec.getFilter(request));
```

If this was straight Repo call I know it, like `save()` is safe against SQL injection, and I know that JPQL is safe when you put parameters in.  But, as I have tested, the above is NOT safe from SQL injection since it's using a concatenated string for the wildcards.  I've seen some examples using the CriteraBuilder and CriteriaQuery to add parameters (ex: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500399/wildcard-escaping-jpa-specifications)), but I am not sure how that will work when you are using the `Specification`s on the service-side.

What I would need to do, I think, is somehow return the `Specification` with `ParameterExpression`s, but I don't know how to set them once the `Specification` is returned to the service class, nor how to add the wildcards such that they don't get escaped.  How do I escape just the passed in value of `containsLowerCase()` above?

Comment: I'm not completely clear what you want to achieve, but I have a hunch that maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/49319419/66686 and the `literal` mentioned therein might help.

Comment: @JensSchauder I'll research the literal a bit more, but basically what I am trying to figure out is how to do parameters with Specifications while setting the value there when the Specification is created, not when I run the query further up the call stack.